# Need help write a Python program that will read this input file and display the following information: sum, average, min, and max of an input file

Tags: python

I have started my code and am on at a very good start, however, I have come to a road block when it comes to adding sum, average, minimum, and maximum to my code, I'm sure this is a pretty easy fix to someone who knows what there are doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The numbers in my file are 14, 22, and -99.
Here is my code so far:

```
def main ():
     contents=''
     
     try:
        infile = openFile()

        count, sum = readFile(infile)

        closeFile(infile)

        display(count, sum)

     except IOError:
          print('Error, input file not opened properly')

     except ValueError:
          print('Error, data within the file is corrupt')


def openFile():
     infile=open('numbers.txt', 'r')
     return infile


def readFile(inf):

     count = 0
     sum = 0

     line = inf.readline()

     while line != '':
          number = int(line)
          sum += number
          count += 1
          line = inf.readline()

     return count, sum          

          
def closeFile(inF):
     inF.close()

def display(count, total):
     print('count = ', count)
     print('Sum = ', total)


main()
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of the file??

Comment: "I have come to a road block" isn't a specific-enough question; please edit the question to describe exactly what the problem is. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: you are jumping around in your code. it will be difficult a fix or add stuff. You should have one function reading the lines and one doing something with the result

Answer (score 0):

In the `while line!=' ':` statement, it will iterate one-one single element in the file, i.e. it will add 1+4 and break the loop when we get " " according to your example. Instead, you can use `.split()` function and use for loop. Your code (Assuming that all numbers are in a single line):

```
def read_file():
    f=open("numbers.txt","r")
    line=f.readline()
    l=[int(g) for g in line.split(",")]     #there should be no gap between number and comma
    s=sum(l)
    avg=sum(l)/len(l)
    maximum=max(l)
    minimum=min(l)
    f.close()
    return s, avg, maximum, minimum

read_file()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a number of antipatterns: you apparently tried to structure it OO-like but without using a class... But this:

```
 line = inf.readline()

 while line != '':
      number = int(line)
      sum += number
      count += 1
      line = inf.readline()
```

is the worst part and probably the culprit.

Idiomatic Python seldom use `readline` and just iterate the file object, *but* good practices recommend to strip input lines to ignore trailing blank characters:

```
for line in inf:
    if line.strip() == '':
        break
    sum += number
    count += 1
```